# How to write new rows to MySQL when a new row is written to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, events, nestjs

I have a legacy database which is MySQL. Right now we are creating a new backend product for legacy product and we want to renew the DB because it has lots of problems. But in any case if my new backend will fail I want to be able to return to legacy system with old db. So with my new PostgreSQL whenever I save a row I want to transform it and save it to MySQL also as a backup and of course for keeping MySQL updated. What is the best solution for a situation like that? Backend framework is NestJS.

Comment: Use a trigger on the Postgres table that writes the row into the MySQL  table using a foreign data wrapper

Comment: see: [foreign data wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html#:~:text=wrapper.%20A-,foreign%20data%20wrapper,-is%20a%20library)

Comment: Note that https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html says the foreign data wrapper module can only connect to an external PostgreSQL instance, not a MySQL instance.

Comment: This one [mysql_fdw](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw)

Comment: Aha, I see, it needs to be built and added to a PostgreSQL or EnterpriseDB instance. It's not a module that comes with the default PostgreSQL product.

Comment: @BillKarwin: no need to build it yourself. It's available through the Postgres [yum](https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/14/redhat/rhel-8-x86_64/) repository (the same repository from which Postgres is typically installed)